# How to make a user's R library available to another user (Linux)

Tags: r, linux

I have R 3.3 installed on a PC running Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca (64-bit). Mostly I use it from my normal user account 'andrew', but sometimes I have to use it on confidential data files that are only available through a VPN, and I have to start R as root in order for that to work.

This works fine, except until today when I tried to use package ggplot2 from R on root and the library(ggplot2) command told me it was not installed, even though it is installed for the andrew account on this PC.

So I tried to install ggplot2 from the root account, but it failed with one of the dependencies. I could try to troubleshoot that failure but last time I did that it was a long and painful process. I should just be able to use the version that is already installed for 'andrew'.

Executing the command library() on both root and andrew, I see that ggplot2 is installed in library

/home/andrew/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3

which is listed as available for andrew but not for root.

I would like to do some action that makes that library also available to root. When I searched for suggestions about this, they recommended changing the .Renviron or .Rprofile file in the home directory, which I believe is /root under this installation. However no files of that name exist anywhere under that directory. Nor do they exist anywhere in the working directory I am using on the VPN.

Can anybody please suggest how to make the library available to root?

Thank you

Andrew

Answer (score 5):

This something I fairly strongly believe it and even tried to set up for the Debian and Ubuntu packages (though it is not currently active).

The key is your value of the library path, ie do

```
.libPaths()
```

on your box, and you are likely to see the dreaded directory below `$HOME` as the first spot.  And *unless you say otherwise* installations will go to  the first spot, hiding "your" packages from other users.

Now, you can do two things:

1. Explicitly install into a different directory. See the options for `install.packages()`
2. Alter the library path.

I usually choose option 2 on our machines at work.  Here is what we have in `${R_HOME}/etc/Renviron` (still showing the comment I added to the R package thirteen (!!) years ago):

```
#R_LIBS_USER=${R_LIBS_USER-'~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3'}
#R_LIBS_USER=${R_LIBS_USER-'~/Library/R/3.3/library'}

# edd Apr 2003  Allow local install in /usr/local, also add a directory for
#               Debian packaged CRAN packages, and finally the default dir 
# edd Jul 2007  Now use R_LIBS_SITE, not R_LIBS
R_LIBS_SITE=${R_LIBS_SITE-'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/library'}
```

You see that `R_LIBS_USER` is commented-out, and `R_LIBS_SITE` default to the standard location below `/usr/local`.

Then:

```
R> .libPaths()
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"       "/usr/lib/R/library"           
R>
```

and packages go into the directory visible to all users (and we make the directory is group-writeable for the proper users).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Dirk. It looks like your first code box above is a configuration file to which you have made some changes. What is the name and likely location of that file under Linux?

Comment: My bad. On Debian/Ubuntu, `/etc/R/Renviron`; normal spot `${R_HOME}/etc/Renviron`.  See `help(Startup)` for all the other choices of setting this, but per your question, system-wide is best.

Comment: Thank you, I made that change, which successfully changed the installation dir, but it also made the ~ library invisible. So in order to be able to access the packages that had previously been installed to ~, I added ~ to the R_LIBS_SITE line by inserting :/home/andrew/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3 before the final ' mark (so it's visible, but no new installations should be installed there). That seems to work. All libraries are now visible to both root and andrew. I then tested a package install and, sure enough, it was installed in '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’', which is great

Comment: Do you think that addition to R_LIBS_SITE is an OK thing to do - ie it will not create other problems?

Comment: Define "problems", please. I am the Debian (and hence Ubuntu) maintainer for this package, and what I detailed is working for a _fairly_ large number of people, or else I'd hear about it.